# grouped / stacked bars disappearing on the left and right in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stackedbarseries

Here is what my `test` data looks like (this is fake data):

```
   Var1 Var2     value
1     A   -7 0.7239130
2     C   -7 0.8326087
3     G   -7 0.7891304
4     U   -7 0.8543478
5     A   -6 0.7673913
6     C   -6 0.8326087
7     G   -6 0.7673913
8     U   -6 0.8326087
9     A   -5 0.8543478
10    C   -5 0.7239130
11    G   -5 0.8760870
12    U   -5 0.7456522
13    A   -4 0.8108696
14    C   -4 0.7456522
15    G   -4 0.8108696
16    U   -4 0.8326087
17    A   -3 0.8543478
18    C   -3 0.7456522
19    G   -3 0.8108696
20    U   -3 0.7891304
21    A   -2 0.7456522
22    C   -2 0.8543478
23    G   -2 0.8326087
24    U   -2 0.7673913
25    A   -1 0.8760870
26    C   -1 0.8326087
27    G   -1 0.5934783
28    U   -1 0.8978261
29    A    0        NA
30    C    0        NA
31    G    0        NA
32    U    0        NA
33    A    1 0.6804348
34    C    1 0.9847826
35    G    1 0.8978261
36    U    1 0.6369565
37    A    2 0.9195652
38    C    2 0.7891304
39    G    2 0.7891304
40    U    2 0.7021739
41    A    3 0.7891304
42    C    3 0.7239130
43    G    3 0.8108696
44    U    3 0.8760870
45    A    4 0.7021739
46    C    4 0.8326087
47    G    4 0.7673913
48    U    4 0.8978261
49    A    5 0.6804348
50    C    5 0.8543478
51    G    5 0.8108696
52    U    5 0.8543478
53    A    6 0.7456522
54    C    6 0.7456522
55    G    6 0.7891304
56    U    6 0.9195652
57    A    7 0.8326087
58    C    7 0.8326087
59    G    7 0.7456522
60    U    7 0.7891304
```

Here is my code for `ggplot2`:

```
  ggplot(data=test, aes(x=Var2, y=value, fill=Var1))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey80","grey20","blue","lightblue"))+
  theme_bw()+
  ylim(0, 1)+
  ggtitle("example")+
  theme(legend.direction="horizontal", legend.key.size=unit(18,"points"), legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(1,0.25), legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-7,7), breaks = round(seq(-7,7)),1)+
  xlab("position")+ylab("arbitrary value")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, linetype=3)
```

Here is the output:

[image: example output]

As you can see, 2 bars on the left and 2 bars on the right are absent from the graph. I do not wish to show any labels on the x-axis outside the -7 to +7 range. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the limits to -7.5 & 7.5, they'll come in

```
ggplot(data=test, aes(x=Var2, y=value, fill=Var1))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey80","grey20","blue","lightblue"))+
  theme_bw()+
  ylim(0, 1)+
  ggtitle("example")+
  theme(legend.direction="horizontal", 
        legend.key.size=unit(18,"points"),      
        legend.justification=c(1,1), 
        legend.position=c(1,0.25), 
        legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-7.5,7.5), breaks = round(seq(-7,7)),1)+
  xlab("position")+ylab("arbitrary value")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, linetype=3)
```